# __getslice__ how do you call it in the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a `class Sentence` with a magic method function `__getslice__`

I am not understanding how to call that function ?

I am trying to do slicing of words. so for example if the string is `"HELLO WORLD, james"` , and I slice it at [0:1] , I expect to get `"HELLO"`

I am getting instead this error: `'method' object is not subscriptable`

Here is my code:

```
    class Sentence:
        def __init__(self, string):
            self._string = string
        def getSentence(self):
            return self._string
        def getWords(self):
            return self._string.split()
        def getLength(self):
            return len(self._string)
        def getNumWords(self):
            return len(self._string.split())
        def capitalize(self):
            self._string =  self._string.upper()
        def punctation(self):
            self._string = self._string + ", "
        def __str__(self):
            return self._string
        def __getitem__(self, k):
            return self._string[k]
        def __len__(self):
            return self._String
        def __getslice__(self, start, end):
            return self[max(0, start):max(0, end):]
        def __add__(self, other):
            self._string = self._string + other
            return self._string
        def __frequencyTable__(self, word):
            count = 0
            for w in self._string:
                if self._string.has_key(word):
                    count = count + 1
            return count
        def __contains__(self, word):
            return word in self._string


def functionTesting():
    hippo = Sentence("hello world")
    print(hippo.getSentence())
    print(hippo.getLength())
    print(hippo.getNumWords())
    print(hippo.getWords())

    hippo.capitalize()
    hippo.punctation()

    print(hippo.getSentence())

    print("HELLO" in hippo)           ##contains

    print(hippo.__getitem__(0))      ##__getitem

    print(hippo.__add__("james"))      ##__add__

    print(hippo.__getslice__[0:1])



functionTesting()
```

Also where can I learn more about magic method functions ? As it seems I am having trouble calling the functions more than writing them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `hippo.__getslice__[0:1]` you are actually trying to slice the method `hippo.__getslice__`. That is why it is failing with the error

```
'method' object is not subscriptable
```

**Important Note:** `__getslice__` is deprecated since Python 2.0 and it is not available in Python 3.x. Quoting the official [documentation of `__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__),

> Deprecated since version 2.0: Support slice objects as parameters to the [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method. (However, built-in types in CPython currently still implement `__getslice__()`. Therefore, you have to override it in derived classes when implementing slicing.)

So you should use [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) for slicing. Quoting the question,

> for example if the string is "HELLO WORLD, james" , and I slice it at [0:1] , I expect to get "HELLO"

Since you want to get words with slicing, if the key passed to `__getitem__` is a [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) object, then call `self.getWords()` and slice the returned object like shown below

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    if isinstance(k, slice):
        return self.getWords()[k]
    return self._string[k]

....
print(hippo[0:1])
['HELLO']
```

**Note 1:** You don't have to explicitly call `__getitem__` when you are  subscripting the `hippo` object. You can simply do

```
print(hippo[0])
# H
```

This will internally call `__getitem__` with `k` as `0`.

**Note 2:** Same as the previous one. You don't have to explicitly call [`__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) and that can be implicitly called with the arithmetic operator `+`, like this

```
print(hippo + "james")
# HELLO WORLD, james
```

**Note 3:** In your `__frequenceTable__` implementation, you are using `has_key` method ([which is a deprecated dictionary method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key) on a string. So, at runtime, your program will fail with

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Perhaps you meant to use `in` operator.

```
def __frequencyTable__(self, word):
    count = 0
    for w in self._string:
        if word in self._string:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

**PS:** I am not sure what this `__frequencyTable__` method tries to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

`__getslice__()` was deprecated in Python 2.6 and is removed in Python 3. You should instead use `__getitem__()` which will receive a slice object when called with slice notation.

i.e.

```
def __getitem__(self, k):
    if isinstance(k, slice):
        # do slice stuff here
    return self._string[k]
```

You can refer to the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for details on all the magic methods.